# "There is/are a fridge, a chair and a table in the kitchen."

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

> There is a fridge, a chair and a table in the kitchen.

or

> There are a fridge, a chair and a table in the kitchen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct version is:

> There is a fridge, a chair and a table in the kitchen

A way to remember this is that saying "a fridge" is like saying "one fridge".

You **wouldn't** say: *there is two fridges*, or *there are one fridge*.

Even when making a list, this rule applies. You would even use "is" if subsequent items in the list were plural, for example:

> In the kitchen there is a table and two chairs.

If the list were the other way around you would use "are":

> In the kitchen there are two chairs and a table.

Comment: There is a fridge, a chair and a table in the kitchen. OR, There are fridge, chair and table in the kitchen.